# OpenERP on Windows kept throwing error when start to work

Tags: python, windows-8.1, openerp-7, liclipse

I have installed openerp on windows 8.1 and when I tried to run a file in Liclipse it shows bellow error. Please be good enough to solve this...  (I am new to Openerp )

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sewwandis\Documents\Workspace\openerp-7.0\openerp-server.py", line 2, in <module>
    import openerp
  File "C:\Users\Sewwandis\Documents\Workspace\openerp-7.0\openerp\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import addons
ImportError: No module named addons
```

Answer (score 0):

**Windows**

- download https://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/exe/odoo_8.0.latest.exe
- run the downloaded file

> Warning
>
> on Windows 8, you may see a warning titled "Windows protected your PC". Click More Info then Run anyway

- Accept the UAC prompt
- Go through the various installation steps

Odoo will automatically be started at the end of the installation.

***Configuration***

- The configuration file can be found at %PROGRAMFILES%\Odoo 8.0-id\server\openerp-server.conf.
- The configuration file can be edited to connect to a remote Postgresql, edit file locations or set a dbfilter.
- To reload the configuration file, restart the Odoo service via Services ‣ odoo server.

If you have more detail Then Show This link

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html